# How to notify my view model that an object inside an observable collection has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, notifications

I have a simple ToggleableObject class that tracks on/off states and an ObservableCollection of that object in my view model.

I know how to trigger an event when an object is added/removed from the collection, but how do I know when objects inside the collection are changed (ideally passing the sender so I know which one)?

The ObservableObject that the ToggleableObject inherits is from CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel and implements INotifyPropertyChanged

XAML:

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ToggleButtons}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

View Model:

```
        public ObservableCollection<ToggleableObject> ToggleButtons { get; set; }
        
        public void DoSomethingIfAButtonIsToggled(object sender)
        {
            // do stuff...
        }
```

ToggleableObject:

```
    public class ToggleableObject : ObservableObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to implement tracking at the ViewModel level, then replace `ObservableCollection` with `BindingList`:

```cs
        public BindingList<ToggleableObject> ToggleButtons { get; } = new();

        public SomeVM()
        {
            ToggleButtons.ListChanged += DoSomethingIfAButtonIsToggled;
        }

        private void DoSomethingIfAButtonIsToggled(object? sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // do stuff...
        }
```

I don't know your implementation of ObservableObject, and if you're using some .Net assembly post-processing package (like Fody), so I can't say for sure if you've implemented ToggleableObject correctly.
With a large degree of probability, the implementation should be like this:

```cs
public class ToggleableObject : ObservableObject
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
    }

    private bool _isChecked;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => _isChecked;
        set => SetProperty(ref _isChecked, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options here:

1. Bind with the IsChecked like you do now (the binding is two-way by default). Emit an event from the ToggleableObject to the viewmodel. But i guess you don't want the ToggleableObject to be a viewmodel. For a one-way or two-way binding, the ToggleableObject should be a viewmodel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
2. Instead of the IsChecked binding, set the Checked and Unchecked event handlers, handle them in the code behind, delegate to the viewmodel and let the viewmodel set the IsChecked on the ToggleableObject. The sender of those eventhandlers will be the CheckBox and ((CheckBox)sender).DataContext will be the ToggleableObject.

The best option would be to implement DelegateCommands btw. Then you can directly bind to a viewmodel instead of using the code behind.

Edit: i didn't know the ObservableObject before, it appears to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged. But you are using it wrong, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject).